# get full path of application directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, directory

I have a website that is using ASP.NET and C#.

I am trying to do something like this

```
bitmap.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\Images\" + imageName + ".png")
```

But I dont want to have to write that whole path, since it changes from computer to computer.
How can I get the full path with C#? (this path is were the application is currently being saved)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
bitmap.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/RELATIVE PATH OF YOUR APPLICATION"), imageName + ".png"));
```

Or some of properties of HttpContext.Current.Request ([ApplicationPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611605/get-full-path-of-application-directory/6611646#6611646) or [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611605/get-full-path-of-application-directory/6611646#6611646), for example)

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the application path

```
string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

Convert virtual application path to a physical path

```
string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(appPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "Folder1\\Folder2\\etc")
```

You can read about MapPath [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,image.png)
```

if i understood your question you want to save it in afolder where your asp.net application is located

else VMATM ans is perfect

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Server.MapPath("imageName + ".png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath can help could help. [Read this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417074237/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121799-1.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to solve it like this:

```
string strPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.{2}", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Images"), imageName, ".png");
bitmap.Save(strPath);
```

The reasons I prefer this approach are:
A)  Its very easy to step through with the debugger and see what strPath is, easier to understand what's happening and fix if its not what you expect.
B)  Using "+" to concatenate strings is a bad habit.  It's less readable, and every time you concatenate the strings the memory is re-allocated... that means lower performance.  You should instead use string.Format OR StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the path to the application root, if you are in a aspx page you can use:

```
Server.MapPath("~/");
```

But if you are in another class that doesn't inherit from Page you can use:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
```

After that use path combine to get the path to the specific file

```
Path.Combine(root, pathFromRootToFile);
```